# Why do Observable Objects notify observers before the change occurs rather than after in Swift?

Tags: swift, observable, implementation, observer-pattern

The new Observation features come with a `withObservationTracking(_ apply:onChange:)` that executes the `onChange` closure when any property accessed in the `apply` closure is modified. However, the `onChange` closure is executed *before* the properties have their new values. Even in the Combine framework, the observers are notified *before* the actual change via `objectWillChange()`.

Why not be notified *after* the change so that we can access the new values then and there? Wouldn't that make things a lot easier rather than setting a flag that'll update all the dependencies next frame?

Is this a design choice or is there a objective reason as to why this is better?

Comment: The `Observable` macro follows the pattern that `ObservableObject` has established for SwiftUI, so the linked Q&A explains the behaviour.